# Construct Boolean masks based on unknown number of columns and values

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to create logical masks based on one or more columns and one or more values in these columns in a pandas dataframe. These masks should then be applied to another column. In the simplest case, the mask might look like this:

```
mask = data['a'] == 4
newData = data['c'][mask]
```

However, more complex cases would also be possible:

```
mask = ((data['a'] == 4) | (data['a'] == 8)) & ((data['b'] == 1) | (data['b'] == 5))
newData = data['c'][mask]
```

In addition, multiple masks might be required. The main issue is that I don't know in advance

- how many masks will be required, and
- how many columns and
- how many values in these columns will define the masks,

as this information would be provided by the user.

I thought that I could ask users to create an input file along these lines:

```
#  <maskName> - <columnName>: <columnValue(s)> - <columnName>: <columnValue(s)> - etc.
maskA - a: 4, 8 - b: 1, 5 - c: 1
maskB - a: 0, 8 - c: 2, 6, 10

targetColumn: d
```

I could then read the input file and loop over it. By appropriately processing the lines, I could identify the number of required masks, the relevant columns, the relevant values, and the column to which the masks should be applied. I could also add this information to lists and/or dictionaries.

However, I'm not sure how best to deal with the issue that I don't know the number of masks/columns/values in advance and how to generate the appropriate masks once I know them. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you can pass strings to `df.query()`, finding the desired subset is really easy as long as you can convert your input format to a string. The parser I've written for your input format isn't super elegant but hopefully you get the idea:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

maskA_str = "maskA - a: 4, 8 - b: 1, 5 - c: 1"
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'a': np.random.randint(1, 10, 100),
     'b': np.random.randint(1, 10, 100),
     'c': np.random.randint(1, 10, 100)}
)

def create_query_str(mask_str):
    mask_name, column_conds = mask_str.split('-')[0], mask_str.split('-')[1:]
    query_str = '('
    column_strs =[]
    for cond in column_conds:
        cond_str = '('
        column, vals = cond.split(':')
        column = column.strip()
        test_strs = ['{c} == {v}'.format(c=column, v=val.strip())
                     for val in vals.split(',')]
        cond_str += ' | '.join(test_strs)
        cond_str += ')'
        column_strs.append(cond_str)
    query_str += ' & '.join(column_strs)
    query_str += ')'
    return query_str

create_query_str(maskA_str)
Out[17]: '((a == 4 | a == 8) & (b == 1 | b == 5) & (c == 1))'

# Can now be used directly in df.query()
df.query(create_query_str(maskA_str))
```

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't aware of the query method! However, unfortunately, it seems it doesn't work when the values are strings, not integers (e.g., `maskA - a: m, n - b: 1, 5 - c: 1`). In the dataframe, the strings will be cast as numpy dtype 'object' and it seems that the query method does not work on these. Would there be a good way around this problem?

Comment: @Troas: I think the query should still work for strings, you just need to quote the string values within the query string, e.g. `((a == 'm' | a == 'n'))`

Comment: You're absolutely right. It does feel sort of strange to quote the strings within the query string, but it does the trick. Thanks!

Comment: `query()` basically uses Python syntax, but treats variable names as the names of the dataframe's columns, rather than objects in the current Python namespace. So, you just use standard Python syntax to check the string. You can still reference Python variables instead of columns, you just need to prefix them with `@`.